# HttpContext.Current Null in CacheItemUpdateCallback

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, dynamic, updatepanel

I am looking to access a method from my current page that creates dynamic controls and appends them to an update panel.  I want to call this method at the end of my CacheItemUpdateCallback to display the new data in cache.

After doing some research it appears that you can not access HttpContext.Current from an asynchronous method because it is thread specific.

Is there a better process to force dynamic content to be refreshed after new values are written to cache or is there a means I can access HttpContext.Current from my CacheItemUpdateCallback?

The method that creates the content, where containers is an array of div objects on my page:

```
public void createInnerHtml()
{
    this.contentLength = ddlContentNumber.SelectedIndex + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.contentLength; i++)
    {
        containers[i].Controls.Clear();
        containers[i].Attributes["Data-Value"] = mainFeeds[i].DataValue.ToString();
        containers[i].InnerHtml = mainFeeds[i].getHeaderString();
        containers[i].Controls.Add(controlManager.getControl(mainFeeds[i]));
    }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do:

```
private void openIncidentsUpdateCallback(string key, CacheItemUpdateReason reason, out object expensiveObject, out CacheDependency dependency, out DateTime absoluteExpiration, out TimeSpan slidingExpiration)
{
    dependency = null;
    absoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(25);
    slidingExpiration = Cache.NoSlidingExpiration;
    expensiveObject = getExpensiveObject() 

    Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    if (page != null)
    {
        ((ReportPage)page).createInnerHtml();
        page.updatePanel1.update()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to create an ajax poll that calls a method that queries the cache object. You cannot update a page from a cache expiration callback as the thread that is used has nothing to do with a request object (it is part of the asp.net/iis process and not anything to do with a HttpRequest (which is where the .Context is populated)).

So basically on the page you need to display the data create either a $.ajax or use an asp.net ATLAS timer (or straight .js ajax if you wish) that calls either a asmx endpoint or a WebMethod which can query the HttpContext.Current.Cache and return the appropriate string/html/json/xml/whatever data.

UPDATE:

There are libraries available for the server updating clients without the programmer understanding/implementing long polling/ polling techniques. Have a look at SignalR http://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: Forgive me I am rather new to asp.net.  What you are saying is to write a method that stores the old values of the data and checks on a time interval if the values change?  Is there a way I can signal when the data is changed instead of checking periodically?

Comment: If you are trying to compare old with new (are they global?) then you can store the old data and the new data in cache and compare them in the server method called by your on page ajax method. Typically you cannot signal from the server to the client without the client performing a poll at intervals to call that server method BUT there are libraries that simplify the long polling technique (have a look at microsofts signalR http://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: Thank you!  After reading further about SignalR and Polling it looks like both of these solutions will work!  Here is an article I was looking at regarding SignalR if it helps anyone else:

http://trycatch.me/using-signlar-to-publish-dashboard-data/